# Coding a fast Memoryscanner with Pointersupport C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, pointers, search

I am currently trying to code a Memoryscanner in C#. The purpose of this program is to allow the user to input a Base/Start address, a range / size, a Pointersize, and Pointerdepth, A search address.

The program will start scanning from the Base Address and will traverse through each pointer (up to a certain depth specified by the Pointerdepth). It will also increment each pointer individually until it reaches the Pointersize, and then move on to the next pointer/offset until it reaches the end of the range / size.

Basically, the program will scan from the start address to the end, exploring each pointer and the entire structure in order to search for a specific address.

Here is an example of how the output will look like, so you can better understand the concept:

```
offset: 0 | Pointers:  - value: 13363688
offset: 4 | Pointers:  - value: 4
offset: 8 | Pointers:  - value: 263502204
offset: 0 | Pointers: 0 - value: 4581392
offset: 0 | Pointers: 4 - value: 4565376
offset: 4 | Pointers: 0 - value: -123456781
offset: 8 | Pointers: 0 - value: 1852138323
offset: 8 | Pointers: 4 - value: 1867653221
offset: 0 | Pointers: 0 | 0 - value: 1458342741
offset: 0 | Pointers: 0 | 4 - value: 367587723
offset: 0 | Pointers: 4 | 0 - value: 141871493
offset: 0 | Pointers: 4 | 4 - value: 277545355
offset: 4 | Pointers: 0 | 0 - value: -123456781
offset: 4 | Pointers: 0 | 4 - value: -123456781
offset: 4 | Pointers: 4 | 0 - value: -123456781
offset: 4 | Pointers: 4 | 4 - value: -123456781
offset: 8 | Pointers: 0 | 0 - value: -123456781
offset: 8 | Pointers: 0 | 4 - value: -123456781
offset: 8 | Pointers: 4 | 0 - value: -123456781
offset: 8 | Pointers: 4 | 4 - value: -123456781
offset: 0 | Pointers: 0 | 0 | 0 - value: -123456781
offset: 0 | Pointers: 0 | 0 | 4 - value: -123456781
offset: 0 | Pointers: 0 | 4 | 0 - value: 0
offset: 0 | Pointers: 0 | 4 | 4 - value: 0
offset: 0 | Pointers: 4 | 0 | 0 - value: 33554481
offset: 0 | Pointers: 4 | 0 | 4 - value: 1006632960
offset: 0 | Pointers: 4 | 4 | 0 - value: 0
offset: 0 | Pointers: 4 | 4 | 4 - value: 0
offset: 4 | Pointers: 0 | 0 | 0 - value: -123456781
offset: 4 | Pointers: 0 | 0 | 4 - value: -123456781
```

While the code works, it is a bit slow to scan larger ranges. I have compared it with the Cheat Engine Structure Spider Scanner which scans the same range much faster..

So I wonder if there is a way to optimize my code for better performance?

This is my current code:

```
 private async Task ReadMemoryAsync()
 {
     int statusUpdateCounter = 0;

     await Task.Run(() =>
     {
         for (int pointerDepth = 0; pointerDepth <= MaxPointerDepth; pointerDepth++)
         {

             for (int offset = 0; offset <= MaxOffsetSize; offset += 0x4)
             {
                 int baseAddress = StartAddress + offset;


                 List<int> pointers = new List<int>(new int[pointerDepth]);

                 ScanPointers(baseAddress, pointers, offset, pointerDepth, ref statusUpdateCounter);
             }
         }
     });

     Console.WriteLine(counter + " results found!");
 }

 private void ScanPointers(int baseAddress, List<int> pointers, int offset, int pointerDepth, ref int statusUpdateCounter)
 {
     bool hasPointers = pointers.Any(); // Check if there are any pointers in the list

     do
     {
         int address = baseAddress;
         if (hasPointers) // Only loop through pointers if there are any in the list
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < pointerDepth; i++)
             {
                 address = ReadMemory(address) + pointers[i];
             }
         }

         int value = 0;

         if (!addressCheckbox.Checked)
         {
             value = ReadMemory(address);
         }

         PrintScanInfo(address, offset, pointers, value, ref statusUpdateCounter);

         UpdatePointersAndFoundAddresses(pointers, address, value, pointerDepth, offset);

         // Carry over if necessary
         if (hasPointers) // Only carry over if there are any pointers in the list
         {
             for (int i = pointerDepth - 1; i > 0; i--)
             {
                 if (pointers[i] > MaxPointerSize)
                 {
                     pointers[i] = 0;
                     pointers[i - 1] += 4;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }

     } while (hasPointers && pointers[0] <= MaxPointerSize); // Continue looping if there are pointers and the first pointer is less than or equal to MaxPointerSize

     // Reset pointers after reaching max depth
     for (int i = 0; i < pointerDepth; i++)
     {
         pointers[i] = 0;
     }
 }

private void UpdatePointersAndFoundAddresses(List<int> pointers, int address, int value, int pointerDepth, int offset)
{
    if (addressCheckbox.Checked)
    {
        if (IsAddressInRange(Convert.ToInt32(ValueAddress.Text, 16), address, address + MaxPointerSize)) //checking if the searched address is within the start and end address
        {
            if (address == Convert.ToInt32(ValueAddress.Text, 16))
            {
                AddToFoundAddresses(pointers, offset); 
            }

            if (pointers.Count > 0)
                pointers[pointers.Count - 1] += 0x4;
        }
        else
        {
            if (pointers.Count > 0)
            {
                pointers[pointers.Count - 1] = MaxPointerSize + 1;
            }

        }
    }
}

private int ReadMemory(int address)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    IntPtr addressPtr = new IntPtr(address);
    int bytesRead = 0;

    if (ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, addressPtr, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, out bytesRead))
    {
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        // Error reading memory
        return -123456781;
    }
}
```

I don't want to look like someone who just copy pastes his entire code here, asking someone to rewrite it for him, that's not what I want. A general direction in what I could do better with some improvement ideas would be appreciated :)